Restore a deleted folder in VS Code
I know I can restore a deleted file in VS Code using Ctrl+Shift+P and Local History: Find Entry to Restore (see, for example, the following question: Restore a deleted file in the Visual Studio Code Recycle Bin).
However, I accidentally deleted a large folder (100ish files) and it would be a pain to restore all files separately. Is there an easier way to restore an entire folder?
The operating system is CentOS 8.
As far as I know, my system does not have its own trash bin, as I am working on a remote compute server.

It would be probably useful to mention your operating system

You may try Local History extension.

I have just tried out this extension, but I don't see how it would help me to recover a deleted file

Ok - it was just trial. What do you think about trying to install trash-cli and run necessary command to restore deleted file? You would run this command in loop iterating to number of files. I'm not sure, if trash-cli works with CentOS though.

@BartłomiejStasiak I resolved my problem in the end by recreating all items in the folder with a script (just empty files with the right name) and then going to ‘timeline’ in VS Code to restore each of them manually. A bit less tedious than going to local file history for each file, but still not ideal. I don’t think I can use trash-cli on the compute cluster, because I don’t have permission to install new software. But I’ll take a look later today.

Nice that you managed to fix it.
